# ADO.NET Source can't aquire a connection to mysql database

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS 2016 project that connects to a MySQL database. It runs fine from SSDT but when I deployed the project and tried to execute from the Integration Services Catalog on the server, I get the following error message:

ADO.NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {5AEB3FC4-B9E1-4AC8-A414-14600F} with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager."

Does anyone seen this problem and do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you installed the MySQL client drivers on the server?

Comment: I have now and that solved the problem.